# List Place Names Using Google Places API and KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to retrieve the names returned by a Google Places API search and list them using KnockoutJS.

I want to search places using Google Places API. I want to mark these places on a map and list their names in an unordered list using KnockoutJS. I am able to places these markers on the map but having trouble listing their names in an unordered list using KnockoutJS. Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<h4>Search Results<h4>
    <ul class="binding" data-bind="foreach: placesArray">
        <li class="binding" data-bind="text: $data">
            <span class="binding" data-bind="text: $index"></span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

What I found extremely difficult is that I am not able to store `placesArray = getNames(results)` in the global variable `placesArray`. I thought it might work if I added knockoutJS locally but `ko.applyBindings` will cause an error if I search for a second time.

```
let placesArray;
function searchPlaces() {
    let bounds = map.getBounds();
    hideMarkers(placeMarkers);
    let placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    let placeName = placeInput.value;
    placesService.textSearch({
        query: placeName, // placeName is a string like "restaurants"
        bounds: bounds
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            createMarkers(results);
            placesArray = getNames(results);
            // placesArray is an array of strings like ["McDonalds", "KFC", "Wendy's",...], I want to list them in <li> //
        }
    });
}

function getNames(placesArray) {
    let placeNamesArray = [];
    for (let i=0; i < placesArray.length; i++) {
        let name = placesArray[i].name;
        placeNamesArray.push(name);
    }
    return placeNamesArray;
}
```

If I introduced KnockoutJS locally, the names were listed correctly but only once, if I run this function a second time. `ko.applyBindings` will throw an error because I apply bindings to the same elements multiple times.

```
function searchPlaces() {
    let bounds = map.getBounds();
    hideMarkers(placeMarkers);
    let placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    let placeName = placeInput.value;
    placesService.textSearch({
        query: placeName,
        bounds: bounds
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            createMarkers(results);
            let placesArray = getNames(results);
            let SimpleListModel = function() {
                this.placesArray = ko.observableArray(placesArray);
            }
            ko.applyBindings(new SimpleListModel());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a viewmodel and the Knockout observable is that you can update it whenever you get any new information and it will be reflected in the HTML. So you could initially create an empty observable and fill it later with the values you search.

```
let SimpleListModel = function() {
    this.placesArray = ko.observableArray();
}
let modelInstance = new SimpleListModel();
ko.applyBindings(modelInstance);

function searchPlaces() {
    let bounds = map.getBounds();
    hideMarkers(placeMarkers);
    let placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    let placeName = placeInput.value;
    placesService.textSearch({
        query: placeName,
        bounds: bounds
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            createMarkers(results);
            let placesArray = getNames(results);
            modelInstance.placesArray(placesArray);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a viewmodel with properties and methods, and it should be instantiated only once. Something like this:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.placesArray = ko.observableArray();

    vm.getNames = function () {
        let placeNamesArray = [];
        for (let i=0; i < placesArray.length; i++) {
            let name = placesArray[i].name;
            placeNamesArray.push(name);
        }
        return placeNamesArray;
    };

    vm.getPlaces = function () {
        let bounds = map.getBounds();
        let placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        let placeName = placeInput.value;

        hideMarkers(placeMarkers);

        placesService.textSearch({
            query: placeName,
            bounds: bounds
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                createMarkers(results);
                vm.placesArray(vm.getNames(results));
            }
        }); 
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Note there's still quite a few undefined variables here (you didn't provide the `createMarkers` and `hideMarkers` functions for example, and `map` and `placeMarkers` will be undefined as well), so this code will not work, but this should be the gist of it.

You should probably also make the `placeInput` a property on your viewmodel (and bind an input field to it using the `textInput` binding), and likely you'll want to execute the `getPlaces` function when it changes, which can also be done with Knockout easily.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me test it.

Comment: Should I put my initMap function that generates the map inside or outside the ViewModel()?